# Auto-login not working after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, auto-login

As per the title. I had auto-login setup (and working) prior to upgrading. My user settings show auto-login set to "On", but I'm being prompted to login every time I reboot. Graphics is ATI Radeon HD 4200.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will reset any issue with the configuration.

1. Goto "All Settings" > "User Accounts"
2. There Unlock button at Top-Right, click it use password.
3. You will see a ON/OFF button for Automatic Login
4. If its ON, make it OFF, and ON again Else make it ON.
5. Click the Lock button, restart you system.

If it does not work, let me know.